# Issues with column wrapping with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am toying with a design using bootstraps grid and running into issues with the content force wrapping or going off-screen. Essentially I want my sidebar with options at a fixed width (about 250px), and its neighboring column to dynamically change size and use the rest of the width.

My thinking was to use the following

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-auto">
    *content fixed width*
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    *content dynamic width*
  </div>
</div>
```

However, my content inside the "col" seems to force it to take the whole width and it drops to a new line. I tried using "flex-nowrap" on my "row", but then my content overflows the column and off-screen to the right. Not sure if I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ben AK! Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the cols in a bootstrap container and give one of them a fixed width.